# Testing whether area around a polygon is obstacle free

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of arbitrary rotated filled rectangles plotted on a Cartesian grid (2D integer array, each cell is either 0 - empty space or 1 - rectangle pixel) and would like to test whether a particular rectangle has any obstacles around it given that the center of rectangle is known along with the coordinates of its four edges.

For example, let's say we want to test if rectangle is obstacle free 5 units from either of its edges.
Rectangles marked with green dot are ok, while the unmarked are clearly collide.
[image]

It seems trivial for non rotated rectangles however, I am having a hard time coming up with algorithm which can handle rotated rectangles.
Simply looping starting from the center till we hit empty space and then checking for obstacles in the empty space doesn't seem to work if rectangles are touching each other.

Comment: What about computing the distance from each vertex to each edge for each rectangle in question?  This assumes you have easy access to each vertex for the rectangles, which I don't know if it's true.

Comment: If you are willing to use the L1 norm (Manhattan Distance) then you can run a flood-fill algorithm that will give a buffer of distances from the rectangle you are checking.  Then you just check whether a bit is set is in a cell with a distance less than 6.  Whether this will be faster or slower than my previous comment depends on your set up.

Comment: I think mixing pixels and vectors here is causing a bit of confusion. Using just the coordinates of the edge line segments you can easily calculate whether two rectangles intersect, no need to consult the pixel data.

Comment: @biziclop The question isn't quite about intersecting rectangles, but your point still stands.

Comment: @GuyGreer flood-fill trick seems like it might just work. Thanks!

Comment: @GuyGreer True, though if you extend your original rectangle by 5 units in each direction, it is. :)

Comment: @biziclop And that occurred to me when you posted your comment, I just didn't think the OP would catch on without explicitly stating that transformation.

Comment: @orom Also these methods will work with any shapes, not just rectangles.  The first algorithm does require the shape to be made up of lines, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be operating with an image-oriented mindset, you can use image processing.

1. Apply a radius-2.5 dilation filter to your image.
2. Treat the image as a graph where there is an edge between two pixels if they both have a red value above some threshold.
3. Any rectangles that have a path between them are at most 5 apart. (Although, note that this will give you the transitive closure of the "too close" relationship.)

Comment: Thanks, I have used flood-fill to solve it as per GuyGreer suggestion, but this idea of image processing is very interesting and is definitely worth checking for anyone stumbling upon this so I'll accept it as an answer.